# Formatting date properly to insert in database using Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have a column in my database with `date` schema.
It accepts string in the form of `2018-02-21`

I have a date value in this form `1/27/18, 4:15 AM`

I need to format the date properly to insert it into the database.

I was trying to use [Carbon Package](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) to format the date, but no luck with it.

```
$date = "1/27/18, 4:15 AM";
$date->format(Y-m-d);
```

Obviously, this didn't work.

Could someone please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your date to timestamp.

```
$date = "1/27/18, 4:15 AM";
$formated_date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($date))->format('Y-m-d');
```

It should works.

If you don't want to use carbon, you can try this with default php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```

Both case output will be

> 2018-01-27

Comment: Happy to hear :)